# no data in dbms_output when fetched via DBMS_SQL

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to retrieving the first name, last name and salary of the employees via dbms_Sql package. The below code is executed successfully but no details are printed. 
**Excepted Output:** 
king Artur 15000
................
jimmy fallon 16000
**Current Output:**
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

```
declare
SH integer ;
output binary_integer;
--
Salary number(10) := 10000;
l_firstname varchar2(50);
l_lastname varchar2(50);
l_salary    number(10);
begin
--
SH := dbms_Sql.open_cursor;
dbms_sql.parse(SH,'select first_name,last_name,salary from employees
where salary > :salary_value',DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);

dbms_sql.bind_variable(SH,':salary_value',salary);

dbms_Sql.define_column(SH,1,l_firstname, 30);
dbms_sql.define_column(sh,2,l_lastname, 30);
dbms_sql.define_Column(sh,3,l_salary);

output := dbms_Sql.execute(SH);

<<dbms_Sql_loop>>
loop

exit when dbms_sql.fetch_Rows(SH) = 0;

/* 
||Retrieve data
||
*/
dbms_output.put_line(l_firstname ||'  '||l_lastname||'  ' || l_salary);

dbms_Sql.define_column(SH,1,l_firstname, 30);
dbms_sql.define_column(sh,2,l_lastname, 30);
dbms_sql.define_Column(sh,3,l_salary);

end loop dbms_Sql_loop;

dbms_Sql.close_cursor(SH);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using dbms_Sql.define_colum instead of dbms_Sql.column_value. 
replace it and it is working fine now.